# Flip animation using chrome's View Transition API not animating background color smoothly

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a simple div that has a background colour and text. Upon a state change, I update this element in the DOM to have a different background colour and text (done via [HTMX](https://htmx.org/)). I want to use Chrome's new [View Transition API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/view-transitions/) so that transition between these two divs has a vertical flip effect.

I have this *almost* working using the following code:

```css
@keyframes flip-in {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flip-out {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
}

::view-transition-old(flip-me) {
  animation: flip-out 0.3s;
}
::view-transition-new(flip-me) {
  animation: flip-in 0.3s;
}

.flip-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3rem;
}

.flip-me {
  view-transition-name: flip-me;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
  <!-- Starting Div -->
  <div class="flip-me old-color">
    Old Text
  </div>
  <!--This div replaces the one above in the transition --> 
  <div class="flip-me new-color">
    New Text
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that during the animation (for both the flip out and flip in) the background colour of the div goes really bright.

How can I maintain the background colour of the div whilst it's animating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was a simple as including opacity into the animation:

```
@keyframes flip-in {
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);  
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes flip-out {
  0%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99%{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```